# Explicit way of finding particular field elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Suppose I am working with the field $\mathbb{F}_{5^2}$ and I know that there exists a primitive element $\gamma$ that satisfies the following equation $\gamma^2 = \gamma + 3$. I want to calculate $b_j$ that satisfies $\gamma^{b_j} = \gamma + j$ for $j = 0,1,2,3,4$. Is there a algorithmic way I can determine those $b_j$ or do I have to go through trial and errors.

Comment: I assume you wanted to write $b_j$ instead of $a_j$ ? Or the inverse ?

Comment: yes I modified it.